# Docker Swarm: Apparent inconsistency

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm

I'm using docker 1.13.1 on CentOS 7. I have created a swarm having a leader and two workers. Here are the nodes:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME           STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
jfyycwch6l1rdarc9j7hd69dg    inf-jenkins04-prd  Ready   Active
jy182rao4rnm3vn1uhm2ghslt    inf-jenkins03-prd  Ready   Active
xuc8l7ra249y7e9s7u778g46l *  inf-jenkins02-prd  Ready   Active        Leader
```

Now, I want to see the details of each node:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker node ps inf-jenkins02-prd
ID  NAME  IMAGE  NODE  DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE  ERROR  PORTS
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]#
```

The command is done on the leader, of course but nothing is displayed. These seems like a major inconsistency as there are no running containers:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]#
```

and also:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]#
```

I have created the cluster with Ansible but I don't think that this detail might be relevant. Does anyone know what might be wrong here ?

Comment: What workload did you put on your Cluster? it seems no containers are deployed yet which is normal.
Unless you did deploy some containers can you share how and the docker-swarm file you used?

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. If there are no tasks executing on those servers, it is normal that you see no task listed there. What am I missing? Also, if what you want is to "see the details" of the node, I would use something like "docker node inspect" and not "ps" to list the tasks.

Comment: The docker documentation says that the command docker node ps <node-name> shows the node details, for example: the node name, its status, etc. But I'm perhaps missinterpreting it and it is not supposed to show anything before services are deployed on the nodes. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: No, no services are deployed yet but I thought that docker node ps would show the details of the given node even if no services are deployed on it. But I probably missunderstood the documentation, in which case is normal that nothing is displayed for a given node if there are no deployed services. Many thanks for your lights.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25528432)

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are using to see the state of the nodes are not the ones you should be using. For having some details on your nodes you can try with things like.

```
docker node inspect
```

or

```
docker system info
```

The commands you are using, are suitable for times when you want to list the "services" (as per docker/swarm perspective) that are currently running.

Just for the sake of testing, you could try to run a container like

`docker container run --name test nginx`

and then execute your

`docker container ls`

Hope this helped!